# Choosing the name of a column when creating a view in Redshift

Tags: sql, database, view, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a view that contains a column with a list of codes. This is the SQL code that I currently have:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS myview;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview as
SELECT 'code1'
UNION
SELECT 'code2'
UNION
SELECT 'code3'
```

This creates a view with this column:

| ?column? |
| --- |
| code1 |
| code2 |
| code3 |

As you can see the column name is "?column?" and I would like to change it to a name of my choice. I've tried looking at the [Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html) where it says that you can specify a column name, but I'm not sure what's the correct syntax since they don't give any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add an alias with the name of column

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW logs.myview as
SELECT 'code1' as my_column
UNION
SELECT 'code2'
UNION
SELECT 'code3';
```